# Received 502 error even though the call suceeded

Tags: c#, httpresponse

We handle our credit card processing through a third party. As far as I can tell what happened to one customer is they submitted a payment, we got a 502 error from the third party, displayed an error to the customer and they tried again getting a success response the second time.

Come to find out, both payments went through successfully so now business is asking our developers how to prevent this from happening.

The request is made through the [WebRequest.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.create?view=netcore-3.1) method. I am guessing that the 502 error occurred somewhere along the return trip back to our servers which is why it succeeded but we thought it failed.

Is there some way to tell from the response which stage the failure occurred? Unfortunately the third party docs have zero information about this particular error.

Comment: Do u use some proxy? Maybe third party is using some ? It is not really what you could fix if you do not control the server/proxy, it is clearly mentioned even here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502

Comment: 502 means that the gateway fronting the remote service did not get the response from their backend, but their backend may have processed the request. I would raise this as a critical bug with the payment gateway and review your legal agreement with them, as liability for this should lie with them.

Comment: This is the 2 generals problem. You need a way to make the transaction idempotent, so the provider will not process a payment for the same invoice twice.

Comment: @Jeremy Lakeman This is probably the closest thing to an answer we can hope for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have 2 systems, which want to be in agreement on an event occurring. Well sorry, but you can't do it.

This is the classic [2 Generals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem) problem. If messages can get lost, there is no protocol to guarantee that 2 parties agree.

The best you can manage is an idempotent transaction. If you have a transaction that you aren't sure about, but which actually worked the first time. Attempting to apply it again should return success, but do nothing.

Look over the payment processor API to see if they have an ID field you can use as an idempotent identifier.